# Why doesn't Django's built-in login work?

Tags: django, authentication

so I was trying to use Django's built-in login with the codes below, but then I ran into a problem. 
With url '.../login' I was able to access the login page, but then when I typed in the username and password (of my superuser account), it did not redirect to any page. 
Moreover, I realized that I was not even logged in, when I tried to access the admin page and it showed me the login window(?).

This is the code in my urls.py in the main folder.

```
urlpatterns = [
    # other stuff ,
    path('', include("django.contrib.auth.urls"))
}
```

And this is my login.html file

```
{% extends 'main/base.html' %}
{% block title %}Log In{% endblock %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

{% block content %}
<form mehtod='post' class="form-group">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{form|crispy}}
    <p>Don't have an account? Create one <a href="/register">HERE</a></p>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Log In</button>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

Finally, I've added the code below to my settings.py

```
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = "/"
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = "/"
```

As well, what I've notices is that as soon as I typed in the username and password and hit 'Log In' button, the url turned into this: 
http://127.0.0.1:8000/login/?csrfmiddlewaretoken=qcPDO9hPSpFTIXyz8f9Tv22qUQttqngKaauJu5HXlRzHtPyqyZ7kPgpWugEmbBGI&username=mySuperUser&password=myPassword 
You should notice that the username and password appeared in the url even though it was a POST method (probably?).

I just cannot understand what went wrong. 
I very much appreciate your help. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The property `mehtod` within your form tag should be `method`

```
<form method='post' class="form-group">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{form|crispy}}
    <p>Don't have an account? Create one <a href="/register">HERE</a></p>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Log In</button>
</form>
```